# Unable to find remote git branch in remote -- BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch, git-fetch

Switched to a new machine. I need to pull the working branches which was pushed from my old machine to remote. But I am unable to find the remote branches via git command. I could see the branch in BitBucket UI.

This search all is not showing the branches

```
git branch -all
```

However I could see my branch in grep search

```
git ls-remote | grep "my_branch_name"

From ssh://git@my_org.com:xxxx/xxxx/xxx.git
ed18a***************************113aa4ac        HEAD
5b9a1***************************f4aa4f3a        refs/heads/feature/mybranch-10XX
704e2***************************2a4586d5        refs/heads/feature/mybranch-5XX
```

Is there anyway to fetch these to my new local ?

Comment: You already tried `git fetch`, right?

Comment: `git fetch` - _"Fetch branches and/or tags (collectively, "refs") from one or more other repositories, along with the objects necessary to complete their histories"_

Comment: yes, after git fetch... only origin/*** branches show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have those branches.  They're named `origin/feature/mybranch-10XX` and `origin/feature/mybranch-5XX`.

Those aren't *branches*, though.  Instead, they're branches.  If you want to work on those branches, you'll need to make branches from those branches.  If this makes no sense, you're reading it right: Git *overuses the word branch so much* that it loses all meaning.  (See [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452))

To make sense out of this, stop calling things "branch" (or at least, not *just* branch).  Use these words:

- remote-tracking name: a name like `origin/main` or `origin/feature/mybranch-10XX`;
- branch name (or "local branch", if you prefer): a name like `main` or `feature/mybranch-10XX`; and
- commit: the thing that is identified by a big ugly hash ID.

Git will *find* the hash ID(s) of commit(s) using the names—the branch names and the remote-tracking names—and will then use those commits to find earlier commits.  The set of commits found by using these names ("branches") is also a "branch".  So depending on what one means when one says "branch", you either do have the branches (the set of commits), or you do have the branches (the remote-tracking names), or you don't have the branches (you lack the local branch names).

Fortunately, if you have a remote-tracking name such as `origin/feature/mybranch-10XX` and you call for Git to switch to a (local) branch name:

```
git switch feature/mybranch-10XX
```

and that branch name *does not exist yet*, this invokes the `--guess` option, which is on by default: `git switch` or `git checkout` *means* `git switch --guess` or `git checkout --guess`.<sup>1</sup>  The guessing code intercepts the error that Git *would have* given, had you used `--no-guess`.  Git was *about* to say something to the effect that there is no local `feature/mybranch-10XX`, but then the guessing code intercepted the error.  The guessing code scans through your *remote-tracking* names looking for one that matches up (after stripping off the `origin/` part in this case).  If it finds one, it *creates* a new *(local) branch name* from the remote-tracking name, identifying the *same commit*.  That commit is now "on" the (local) branch *and* "on" the remote-tracking name.  It may also be on many other branches: commits are often on many branches at the same time, in Git.

In any case, now that `git switch` or `git checkout` has used the guessing code to *create* the branch name, Git can switch *to* that branch.  You will now have that particular *commit* checked out and can begin making changes and using those to make new commits.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you *don't* want Git to guess, turn this off with `--no-guess`.  In modern versions of Git you can also disable it by default as a configuration option.